# Keras-SegNet use ImageDataGenerator and fit or fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation, keras-layer

Problems about import data set is going to drive me crazy.

This is part of my segnet code.

I'll focus on the questions about image&mask data import.

```
print("CNN Model created.")

###training data
data_gen_args = dict()
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
seed1 = 1
image_datagen.fit(images, augment=True, seed=seed1)
mask_datagen.fit(masks, augment=True, seed=seed1)

train_image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_im,target_size=(500, 500),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, class_mode = None)
train_mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_mask,target_size=(500, 500),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, class_mode = None)

train_generator = zip(train_image_generator,train_mask_generator)

###validation data
valid_gen_args = dict()
val_image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**valid_gen_args)
val_mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**valid_gen_args)
seed2 = 5
val_image_datagen.fit(val_images, augment=True, seed=seed2)
val_mask_datagen.fit(val_masks, augment=True, seed=seed2)

val_image_generator = val_image_datagen.flow_from_directory(VAL_im,target_size=(500, 500),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, class_mode = None)
val_mask_generator = val_mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(VAL_mask,target_size=(500, 500),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, class_mode = None)

val_generator = zip(val_image_generator,val_mask_generator)

###
model.fit_generator(
train_generator,steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//BATCH_SIZE,epochs=EPOCHS,validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=nb_validation_samples//BATCH_SIZE)
```

> My question is:

1. I change the input size to 500*500, so I adjusted the pooling and upsample layers size. Is this achievable?
   Further more, can I make the classic net(Like AlexNet, VGG, Segnet...) accept arbitrary input image size by adjusting their pooling and upsample layers size and filter numbers?
2. I'd like to know what is the data type of variables "images" and "masks" in:

   ```
   image_datagen.fit(images, augment=True, seed=seed1)
   mask_datagen.fit(masks, augment=True, seed=seed1)
   ```

   This part is from Keras official tutorial.(Ans:Now I know they both are numpy arrays.)
3. According to the question above. How can I derive them?

   Should I write a function like mnist.load_data() below?

   I need some examples.

   ```
       (x_train_image, y_train_label), (x_test_image, y_test_label) = mnist.load_data()
   ```
4. I use the function

   ```
   flow_from_directory
   ```

   Does it mean there is no need to define a function like
   "mnist.load_data()" by myself, and I can use it to get the (batch,shuffle) data directly from my directory structure?

This is my directory structure:

```
Dataset -training----------images----"many images"
           |         |
           |         |-----mask-----"ground truth images(mask)" 
           |
           |
       validation----------val_images----"many images"
           |        |
           |        |------val_mask------"ground truth images(mask)" 
           |
           |
        testing---------------test images (no ground truth)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you sure that the ImageDataGenerator can actually be used with a segmentation problem? To my knowledge it will randomly read images from the directory, but of course you need a matching pair between images and masks.

Comment: @pietz I read Keras offical tutorial: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
You can search for the key word 'Example of transforming images and masks together.' in the page.

I guess it can.
I saw some keras segnet examples in github.

Comment: Not much experience with ImageDataGenerator but looking at the docs the `fit` method is only needed to compute sample statistics for image normalization. It's only required if you're using `featurewise_center`, `featurewise_std_normalization` or `zca_whitening`. Are you? In that case images and masks are sample data to compute statistics from.

Comment: Yes, for these 3 options your training data has to be analyzed beforehand. It has nothing to do with the actual training/fitting of your model.

Comment: @filippo I did the images preprocess first, so I don't need them I guess.
I just want the "generator" function it provide.
Since keras examples in github usually define the generators by themselves.I don't really understand what ImageDataGenerator  can do...

Comment: @WeiminChan I usually write my own generators so as I said I don't have much experience but as far as I recall there're a couple of options to save generated data to a directory. Set them, do a couple iterations using it just like a python iterator and see what it produces. That would be the input of your network if you use it with `Model.fit_generator`

Comment: @pietz You mean I need to defined a function which can import my images in batches and do shuffle, then generate infinitely by myself, or I cannot use the fit and fit_generator ?

Comment: @WeiminChan it seems like the IDG now supports segmentation data by feeding the same seed for images and masks. just like filippo I like to use my own logic for reading data. The IDG can take care of reading your images, providing labels for classification automatically and augmenting your images during training based on settings you provide. its a cool tool.

Comment: @filippo Actually I'm a beginner in Keras. I learn tensorflow for about six months. I confused with the large-scale tf code, so I try do search another one which I can do the deep learning.
Can I take a look on your code? I don't really understand what does mnist.load_data() do, so I can not write one fit my needing.
This is the dataset I use.
https://project.inria.fr/aerialimagelabeling/

Comment: @WeiminChan When using the IDG you want to use the fit_generator function for the training of your model. The generator fit() function (not to be confused with the model fit() function) is only necessary if you augment your data using any of the 3 mentioned settings above.

Comment: @pietz I see, so I just need a mnist.load_data() like function(Maybe define by myself....oh my...) to provide training data ,validation data and testing image in a batch size which are numpy arrays, and feed them in the fit() function right?

Comment: @WeiminChan (I deleted my previous comment, because I missunderstood) Yes, but you don't need to worry about the batchsize when building your data in numpy arrays.

Comment: @WeiminChan And could you maybe tidy up your initial post with a clear question what it is you want, so someone can type up an answer to your problem.

Comment: @pietz Done.It's my pleasure to have a discussion with you.You do gave me a big favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get to it.

1. SegNet is a FCN (fully convolutional network --> it doesn't use dense layers) that works with any input/output size you specify. Let me just recommend to use mutiples of 16 for these encoder-decoder architectures. Why? Because in your case we will go from 500 to 250 to 125 to 62 and on the other side from 62 to 124 to 248 to 496. Suddenly your resolutions don't match anymore. AlexNet and VGG use dense layers. This means you can change the initial input size that fits your need, but you won't be able to use pretrained weights from different resolutions. The number of parameters simply don't match. Side note: VGG and AlexNet are classification architectures, whereas SegNet is a segmentation architecture.
2. `images` and `masks` are 4-dimensional numpy arrays with a shape of `(num_imgs, width, height, num_channels)`. Where are these variables coming from? You must have read them from their respective image files in an earlier step.
3. You want to iterate over each of the two folder, read each image, add them to a list and once you're done convert this list to a numpy array. Make sure images and masks are sorted the same way so that they match each other.
4. `flow_from_directory` is a function that can be used with a IDG in order to read images for you. Very handy. However, it only let's you get around this, if you don't need `featurewise_center`, `featurewise_std_normalization` and `zca_whitening` because in this case you need already available numpy arrays in order to execute the IDG `fit()` function. Btw, this fit function has nothing to do with the `fit()` function that starts the training of your model. It just uses the same naming convention.

Comment: 1. Actually, I adjusted the pooling kernel size in encoding process and decoding process into two 2*2 and two 5*5.But I have not compiled it.Is this approach achievable?

Comment: ok, that might work too. i think you will notice that 500x500 is pretty large and will therefore take quite some time to train. I'd recommend experimenting with a 224x224 pipeline as well and see if you really need the resolution.